# Why is my simply cross fade not repeating?

Tags: jquery, css, slider, fade

I have a simple background image cross fader: http://jsfiddle.net/jRDkm/2/ The basis for this code was taken from here: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow

For some reason though it does only one repetition then fades to white. How can I tweak my code so that it constantly repeats itself?

JS:

```
function slideshow() {
$('#fullscreen-slider li:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
    $('#fullscreen-slider :first-child').fadeOut()
    .next('li').fadeIn()
    .end().appendTo('#fullscreen-slider');
}, 3000);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. Try

```
$('#fullscreen-slider li:first').fadeOut()
        .next('li').fadeIn()
        .end().appendTo('#fullscreen-slider');
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jRDkm/5/

Comment: You would have noticed it using firebug and watching the changes in HTML content of `#fullscreen-slider`.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jRDkm/6/)**</kbd>

```
/* located within plugins.js */
function fitElements() {
    $('ul#fullscreen-slider li').height( $(window).height() ).width( $(window).width() );
}

function slideshow() {
    var n = 0;
    var $LI =  $('#fullscreen-slider li');
    $LI.hide().eq(n).show();
    setInterval(function(){
        $LI.eq(n++%$LI.length).fadeTo(600,1).siblings().fadeTo(600,0);
    }, 3000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    fitElements();
    slideshow();
});
```

Comment: woah man you pasted whole code. How you made that Live Demo button ?

Comment: @AspiringAqib :) hit the *|edit|* link and see for your self :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :  http://jsfiddle.net/jRDkm/4/

```
function slideshow() {
    $('#fullscreen-slider li:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#fullscreen-slider li:eq(0)').fadeOut()
        .next('li').fadeIn()
        .end().appendTo('#fullscreen-slider');
    }, 3000);
};
```